# Replacing characters and putting them back together

Tags: vb.net

So I thought I'd give making encryption software a go in the Visual Basic.
Pretty much I have two lines, one for encryption, and the other for decryption. I also have a key that's set earlier on.

Encyption:

```
Message = Message.Replace("A", A).Replace("B", B).Replace("C", C) // ...goes on to "z"
```

Decryption:

```
Message = Message.Replace(lz, "z").Replace(ly, "y").Replace(lx, "x") // ...goes on to "A"
```

My problem is following. We will use my default key just for example, which is `QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!@#$%^&*()-+=`. My Variable `A` is equal to the first letter in the key, for this example it is Q. So any "A"'s in my message will be turned into Q's. The problem comes when I try to turn them back, for decryption, my "Q"'s will turn into whatever Variable Q is. And, in this case, variable `Q` is equal to "J" since `Q` is equal to whatever is at the 17th position in my key.

So in the end, if I try to Encrypt "A", and then Decryption turns it into "J". Of course the whole message gets messed up. Anyone got any ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: Visual Studio is **not** a programming language, it's an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for multiple languages, so your question doesn't make a sense a bit.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy sorry, fixed it, I meant Visual Basic

Comment: You didn't change the tag, which is more important. I took a care of it.

Comment: By keep doing `.Replace()` you replace characters that have already been encrypted. Use a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` and iterate though all the characters one by one instead. During the iteration construct a string where every char you append is the old char's respective value from the Dictionary.

Comment: @VisualVincent thats why on the decryption side, I start at lower case z and go to captial A, while on encyption side I start at captial A and go to lower case Z. Although I will look into this Dictionary method, never heard of it until now. And im a bit confused on what you mean by "construct a string where every char you append is the old char's respective value from the Dictionary."

Comment: He means have 2 strings, eg OriginalMessage and EncryptedMessage.  Read each character from OriginalMessage, 1 at a time, and add the encrypted version of it to EncryptedMessage, which starts off empty.  And using a lookup table (eg Dictionary) is the best way to convert the 1 character

Comment: What I meant by constructing a new string is something like this: `string decrypted = "";` _then **inside** your loop:_ `decrypted += MyDictionary(<current char>);`. You just keep adding one char at a time in the loop, where `<current char>` is the current character you're at in the original string.

Comment: Like Stuart said, in the Dictionary you have the original letter as key and the encrypted letter as value, ex: `'A' -> 'Q', 'B' -> 'F', etc.`. When you do `MyDictionary('A')` it will return the encrypted letter `Q`, just add them one-by-one to your encrypted string.